# Trying to build RegEx that uses negative lookahead within a negative character set

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to break down the parameters of the query portion of a URL. Here is my RegEx:

```
private static final String PARAMS_PATTERN = "([^\\?&#=]*)=([^&#]*)";
```

Here's the code where I iterate through matches:

```
Map<String, String> queryMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
Matcher paramsMatcher = Pattern.compile(PARAMS_PATTERN).matcher(this.query);
while (paramsMatcher.find())  
{
    queryMap.put(paramsMatcher.group(1), paramsMatcher.group(2));
}
```

That works fine except in the case of URLs that contains another URL as a parameter, which also contains query parameters, in which the ampersands have been HTML escaped to:

```
&amp;
```

Example:

```
http://www.example.com/path/to/something?param1=foo&param2=bar&url=http://www.example.com/path/to/something?param1=foo&amp;param2=bar
```

I realized that the URL was invalid (not before wasting 15 minutes), but I'm curious just what sort of regular expression would actually capture that last parameter as a single group.

I tried building a negative lookahead within the negative character set, but that is not working. My attempt:

```
([^\\?&(?!(?:apos|quot|lt|gt|amp);|#)#=]*)=([^&(?!(?:apos|quot|lt|gt|amp);|#)#]*)
```

I haven't been able to find an answer as to whether or not lookahead like this within a character set is actually permitted, but that RegEx doesn't work according to [Regexr](http://regexr.com) and [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html). Anyone able to satisfy my curiosity?

Comment: What exactly would a look(ahead|behind) _inside a character set_ even mean?

Comment: You can't have a lookahead within a character set. The expression `[^&(?!(?:apos|quot|lt|gt|amp);|#)#]` is same as `[^&(?!:apos|qutlgm);#]` and matches anything but the characters listed.

Comment: Perhaps you should read the **documentation** on what a Character Set is and how it works, e.g. http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: You are confusing two different problems.  `&amp;` is an XML/HTML escape known as an [entity](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-references) and has nothing to do with URLs.  You should be using an XML or HTML parser to obtain your URL value, so that such character entities are already decoded.

Answer (score 1):

> I haven't been able to find an answer as to whether or not lookahead like this within a character set is actually permitted

Of course it isn't, since a *character set*, as the term suggests, consists of characters, not regular [lookahead] expressions. However, we don't need anything like *a negative lookahead within the negative character set* here — as it is common with double negations, they cancel each other out and can be replaced by a positive construct. In the case at hand we need to match not less, but more of the parameter value, so we can just add the additional alternatives by replacing the subpattern `[^&#]` with `([^&#]|&(apos|quot|lt|gt|amp);)`, i. e. use:

```
private static final String PARAMS_PATTERN = "([^\\?&#=]*)=(([^&#]|&(apos|quot|lt|gt|amp);)*)";
```